# Prestashop - how do I write to a log file?

Tags: logging, module, prestashop

What php code should I use in a Prestashop module to write to a log file? I have used

```
Logger::addLog("something",1);
```

but it does not work.

Comment: A possible  duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129993/where-does-prestashop-loggeraddlog-save-the-log-file

Answer (score 8):

You can also store the log in file using below code.

```
$logger = new FileLogger(0); //0 == debug level, logDebug() won’t work without this.
$logger->setFilename(_PS_ROOT_DIR_.”/log/debug.log”);
$logger->logDebug(“message 1″);
$logger->logDebug(“message 2″);
```

It will work!.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The log is saved in database in 'log' table (with your current prefix);

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use [PHP's](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
file_put_contents(_PS_ROOT_DIR_ . '/path/to/logfile',
                  $data . "\n",
                  FILE_APPEND);
```